# NSDocument window controller and outlet instantiation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview, nswindowcontroller, document-based

I have what it seems to be a weird problem with an instance of a document window controller. I have a document-based application with a custom window controller inited from overridden `makeWindowControllers` method of NSDocument main class:

```
- (void)makeWindowControllers
{
     docWinController = [[DocumentWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MainDocument" owner:self];
     [self addWindowController:docWinController];
}// end makeWindowControllers
```

The main application window contains an NSTextView object with a corresponding outlet in the file owner (the above window controller). I have an action that is called via a menu item and should set the content of the text view textStorage object.

Now, the action works as expected when the sender is, for example, a button in the window but does not work when the sender is the menu item. I expect to be an instantiation issue, but what is puzzling is that providing the following line in the action:

```
[[[textView textStorage] mutableString] appendFormat:@"Some text...%@\n", self];
```

returns two different window controller instance id's, depending on the sender (interface button or menu item). In one case (menu item), the NSLog spits:

```
-[DocumentWindowController myAction:] [L119]: Some text...<DocumentWindowController: 0x100195870>
```

in the other case (the button):

```
-[DocumentWindowController myAction:] [L119]: Some text...<DocumentWindowController: 0x113e72120>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What’s the type of the file’s owner in MainDocument.nib? You’re passing `self` (a document) to `-initWithWindowNibName:owner` but you say that the owner is the window controller. There seems to be something odd in your configuration but I can’t tell what it is from your original question.